# ¿Existe una manera de usar un solo archivo JS para varios archivos HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy creando un programa web simple ABM o CRUD (como ustedes lo conozcan). Mi archivo JS funciona perfectamente con su HTML, el problema surge cuando uso este mismo JS para otro HTML. No puedo encontrar una manera de usar el JS para todos los HTML.

Intenté con jQuery pero no cargo los datos correspondientes en la tabla , cargo datos del otro HTML.

```
(In this file the JS works)CPU.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 ...
<script src="../js/funciones.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



 (In this file does not work)MOTHERBOARD.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 ...
<script src="../js/funciones.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que los datos se carguen correctamente en la tabla MOTHERBOARD.html, pero solo carga los datos de la tabla CPU.html. Yo uso el mismo JS porque son las mismas funciones para todos los html. También aclaro que todos los html tienen el mismo código.

Comment: Hola, podes facilitarnos el código JS y los HTML, porque seguro que allí está el error

Comment: ¿Los estás cargando al final del `<body>`?  ¿Por qué en la cabecera? ¿Todos los archivos están en la misma carpeta?

Comment: @SergioKaznowiecki son 350 lineas de código en mi JS, por donde las paso ? Soy nuevo en esto ,sepan entender.

Comment: @A.Cedano  cargo el JS al final del body como corresponde.

Comment: Yo uso la pagina https://pastecode.xyz/ para pegar el codigo ahi, y despues paso el link.

Comment: Yo tengo entendido que es mejor poner el JS en la cabecera, no al final del `body`. Y, es importante que nos digas si los archivos están todos ubicados igual, porque usas rutas relativas para incluir el JS.

Comment: @Sergio aca estan los links, te aclaro que tanto el cpu.html como el motherboard.html tienen el mismo codigo. funciones.js: https://pastecode.xyz/view/8ea2ad58 , cpu.html: https://pastecode.xyz/view/ec0a2bf1 ,
 mother.html: https://pastecode.xyz/view/877867b4.

Comment: @LucianoValenzuela yo pondría la referencia la JS en la cabecera.

Comment: ¿Porque en la cabecera?, me gustaria saber. En la facultad me han enseñado que en la cabecera van todos los CSS y al final del body los JS ya que primero es mejor que se cargue la pagina y despues sus scripts. (Es lo que me han enseñado). @ValVert

Comment: Exactamente, el navegador crea el DOM formado por HTML luego CSSOM formado por CSS y posteriormente ejecuta JavaScript por lo que la forma en que lo pones esta bien: ya que cuando el navegador va a dibujar tu pagina recorre el html y cuando se encuentre con css se bloquea el dibujo de tu pagina y se descargan los estilos luego continua dibujando la pagina y si se encuentra con un js se vuelve a bloquear para descargar los archivos, eso hará lenta su pagina y que luego de varios segundos de pantalla aparezca repentinamente la pagina cargada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En esta parte

```
        //url1 ajax
        ajaxObj.url = '/controlador/ruteador/ruteador.js/listar/cpu';
        jQuery.ajax(ajaxObj);
        //url2 ajax

        ajaxObj.url = '/controlador/ruteador/ruteador.js/listar/mothers';
        jQuery.ajax(ajaxObj);
```

Estas ejecutando las 2 peticiones ajax y los estas renderizando en la misma tabla. Me hace un poco de ruido esa parte; lo que yo haria es agregarle una etiqueta en el html de cada una de las paginas y preguntaría por esta etiqueta y ejecuto un solo ajax.

Algo asi :

```
const page = $("#pageName").val();
if(page == 'cpu')
  ajaxObj.url = '/controlador/ruteador/ruteador.js/listar/cpu';
else
  ajaxObj.url = '/controlador/ruteador/ruteador.js/listar/mothers';

jQuery.ajax(ajaxObj);
```

Y en tu archivo cpu.html agregaria algo asi :

```
<input id="pageName" type="hidden" value="cpu"/>
```

Y en tu metherboard.html agregaria:

```
<input id="pageName" type="hidden" value="metherboard"/>
```

Y en el .js cambiaria el :
     UI.prototype.rellenarTabla(datosRecibidos); 
por

```
UI.rellenarTabla(datosRecibidos);
```

Saludos

Comment: Genial!! Sos el mejor , me funciono a la perfección. Lo sabia estoy un poco flojo de lógica  jaja , saludos y gracias!. @Sergio